# insert ignoring duplicates using TSQL

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, constraints

I have a table with unique constraint on 2 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE MIGRATION_DICTIONARIES.dbo._TableQueue_ (
    Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    TableName VARCHAR(250),
    TableFrom VARCHAR(250),
    KeyName VARCHAR(250),
    Processed INT DEFAULT 0,

    CONSTRAINT [UQ_codes] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
    (
        TableName, TableFrom
    )
)
```

In a procedure I am trying to implement I need to insert a bunch of records using INSERT INTO (...) SELECT. Now, how can I make sure that any rows that duplicate the constraint will be ignored but all the other rows given by the select statement still saved?

The query with insert:

```
INSERT INTO MIGRATION_DICTIONARIES.dbo._TableQueue_ (TableName, TableFrom, KeyName)
SELECT 'some_table_name', t.name as TableWithForeignKey, c.name as ForeignKeyColumn 
from sys.foreign_key_columns as fk
inner join sys.tables as t on fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id
inner join sys.columns as c on fk.parent_object_id = c.object_id and fk.parent_column_id = c.column_id
where fk.referenced_object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'some_table_name')
```

[EDIT]
I ended with following query:

```
MERGE MIGRATION_DICTIONARIES.dbo._TableQueue_ AS T
USING (
    SELECT 'SomeTable' as TableFrom, t.name as TableWithForeignKey, c.name as ForeignKeyColumn 
    from sys.foreign_key_columns as fk
    inner join sys.tables as t on fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id
    inner join sys.columns as c on fk.parent_object_id = c.object_id and fk.parent_column_id = c.column_id
    where fk.referenced_object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'SomeTable')
) AS S
ON (T.TableName = S.TableWithForeignKey AND T.TableFrom = S.TableFrom)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (TableName, TableFrom, KeyName)
    VALUES (S.TableFrom, S.TableWithForeignKey, S.ForeignKeyColumn);
```

But when I run it I still get constraint error:

```
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_codes'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo._TableQueue_'. The duplicate key value is (UP_Opiekun, UP_Uczen).
The statement has been terminated.
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: What version of SQL Server please?

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2008 you can use the [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb522522%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) statement with only a "WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET" clause to INSERT. Don't use a "WHEN MATCHED" clause

More generally, you can also use

```
INSERT dbo._TableQueue_
   (....)
SELECT
   ...
FROM
   SOurce S
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
      FROM dbo._TableQueue_ T
      WHERE
         S.TableName = T.TableName AND S.TableFrom = T.TableFrom
      )
```

After comment:

```
MERGE INTO dbo._TableQueue_ T
USING Source S
       ON S.TableName = T.TableName AND S.TableFrom = T.TableFrom
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
   INSERT (...)
   VALUES (S.x. S.y, ...);
```

Comment: It'll be running on 2012 so the solution with matched could be useful. However, how should I use merge in place of insert into select statement? Could you provide some example?

Comment: Huh, seems easy when you have a concrete source as a table but what about more complex query? I added the query with insert I need to use in main post.

Comment: Look at the MSDN examples. You simply put the source query in ( ) as per example A in my link.